# Button click to use RecyclerView Adapter position

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have created a RecyclerView adapter which looks as following:

[image]

I have added to the Adapter an `onClick` which works when each row is clicked.

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(mView.getContext(), "person + " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} );
```

However, the only button that I really need is the `"chat"` `Imagebutton`.
I had like that only when the user clicks on the chat button it will know which row of the adapter was clicked and based on it will create activity.

Is there a way for me to implement the adapter onClick call when I actually click on the button? Or more specifically, is there a way I can pass to `chatButton.onClick` the position of the row where it is placed?

Because I dont want the whole row to be clickable, only the chat button.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use like this:

```
holder.itemView.chatView.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Toast.makeText(mView.getContext(), "person + " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thank you mate! Is there a way to use it from the main activity tho and not from the adapter activity?